# How to go from a deployed ember project to local development project?

Tags: ember.js, deployment, proxy, ember-cli

I'm using a deployed github repo project as a starting point for my own development project.  Using ember-cli and `ember serve` I get a server running on localhost:4200.  But it says

```
Proxying to https://xxxxx.yyy
```

where xxxxx.yyy is the website of the official deployed project, and the localhost:4200 server interacts with the deployed project's databases.

How do I tell ember to start a completely new local server that creates local empty databases, instead of proxying to the deployed website?

I tried `ember build --environment=development`, and it rebuilt, but it acts the same.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by the term "create local empty database". Ember is a frontend framework. It may use a client-side database in the browser (e.g. local storage or IndexDB) but I'm not sure if that's what you mean. Ember CLI Mirage provides another database like solution but that's only in memory meant for rapid prototyping and testing. The server provided by Ember CLI is only meant for development similar to php's built-in webserver.

Comment: jelhan, since I'm a beginner at this what I meant was for ember to look only locally for databases.  How they get created I'm about to explore.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that you are aware that Ember is not connecting directly with databases like mySQL, PostgreSQL etc. but through an API (Rest, GraphQL etc). Except for the minor case of using in-browser databases like local storage or IndexDB. But if I got it right, Buck Doyle already gave the answer you are looking for: change the proxy path to target a local development API.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a proxy configured in the `.ember-cli` file, as described [in the guides](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/appendix/configuration/). If you remove that property, Ember CLI should no longer use a proxy.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right that was the source of the proxy path.  It looks like this particular project needs some proxy for some of the modules, so it turns out I had to use `ember serve --proxy http://localhost:4200/`